# What are the main files used by GRUB bootloader on legacy and UEFI BIOS?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bios, bootloader

I have a small project where I need to configure a custom board with legacy BIOS, and another with UEFI BIOS. Therefore I would like to understand what GRUB files do we need for each type of BIOS.

I am a little lost about the files needed for a successful boot using GRUB bootloader. I saw multiple files like bootx64.efi, boot.img, core.img, core.efi, grubx64.efi... And honestly, I cannot make the link between them and which is used in which type of situation (UEFI BIOS, Legacy BIOS...)